# chance probability question (statisitics)

Tags: statistics

Hi Im just about to finish my dissertation and I wondered if anyone could help apply a statisitical analysis. Basically I have 2 identical 96 well plates with substrate in each well and 2 wells on each plate are positive values. The positives are on the same positions on each plate (which is expected as they are duplicate plates). I just wanted to know what is the probability of these positive values all being due to chance. - if you could provide a basic explanation too that would be so helpful.

Thanks again
Joe

Comment: Joe Biggs: Do not duplicate your questions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the question asks. What is the probability that, if you pick two wells out of 96 randomly, that they will coincide with the positions on the first plate?

The answer to that is:
 There are ${96\choose 2} = 96*95/2$ ways to pick 2 wells out of 96 given ones (look up "combinations number"). So the probability is $1/4560$.

Comment: Basically, I want to know what is probability that 2 wells on each plate (out of 96) come up positive and match perfectly.